# How do I render an image from a Twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I cannot get this to render out. This is what I get with `{{ kint(paragraph.field_image.value) }}`.

> [image: screenshot]

If this makes any difference, the image is uploaded through a media entity browser widget.

How do I render an image from a Twig template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just use `{{ content.field_image }}`

Here is an example of a template file from a paragraph

```
{%
  set classes = [
  'paragraph',
  'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
  view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
]
%}
{% block paragraph %}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {% block content %}
      <div class="row collapse expanded mainsection">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
              {{ content.image }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

Notice that I only need to write `{{ content.FIELDNAME }}`, if I wrap everything in a `{% block content %}`

Comment: I'm still learning what the meaning of blocks are in twig templates, I have seen them in template files but this was new to me, thanks for sharing.